# Question over proving normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a group, then the center of $G$, assume its $Z(G)$, is the set of all elements of $G$ which commute with everything. So $Z(G)$ $=$ {$x$ $\in$ $G$: $xy$ $=$ $yx$ for all $y$ $\in$ $G$}. Prove that $Z(G)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ for any group $G$.

First I need to show  $G$ is a subgroup; and then show it's normal.

To show its a subgroup I know I need to prove that it has an identity, all elements contain inverses and it is closed under the operation

Comment: Can you prove it has the identity? That it's closed under inverses and the operation? Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

It should be clear that $1_G \in Z(G)$, but even if not, showing inverses and closure is enough to show $Z(G)$ contains the identity. For inverses: take arbitrary $x \in Z(G)$ and $g \in G$. Then we have:

$$x^{-1}g = (g^{-1}x)^{-1} = (xg^{-1})^{-1} = gx^{-1} \Rightarrow x^{-1} \in Z(G).$$

Can you do a similar thing to show that for $x,y \in Z(G)$, we have $xy \in Z(G)$? Showing it's normal is very easy once you use the commutativity property.

Comment: Actually, you also need to prove that $Z(G)$ is non-empty (and generally the easiest way to show that a subset of a group is non-empty when we want to show that it is a subgroup is to show that it contains the identity).

Comment: @fkraiem thank you, that was sloppiness on my part.

Comment: Hmm, how do I show its normal though?

Comment: @RoyM. Did you try? Do you know what it means to say that it's normal?